# How do I declare a shorthand reference to a static class with a very long name?

Tags: c#

For example:

```
public static class aVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongName { public static void methodOne() }
```

then in my code just be able to write something like:

```
x = aVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongName

x.methodOne
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You *can* use a [`using` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) to create an alias:

```
using Foo = SomeVeryLongNameIndeed;

...


Foo.MethodOne();
```

I'd be more tempted to see if you could fix the name to something more palatable though, if it's under your control :)